# failed to instantiate SLF4J on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, instantiation, slf4j

I am using the -libjars command to run my jar on hadoop and have set up .run() and ToolRunner in my driver program. (This program has no map/reduce, only PutMerges files to HDFS).
When I export the jar using eclipse, the program works perfectly. But I need to build the jar with only my own .class files and import 3rd party libraries during execution.

my cmd is:

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar package.classname -libjars mypath/logback-core-1.0.1.jar,logback-classic-1.0.1.jar,jul-to-slf4j-1.6.4.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar,slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar,log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

the error is:

`Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:143)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 9 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
        at     org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:143)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:         ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 9 more`

I have checked that 628  03-07-12 07:33   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException.class does indeed exist in my logback.core. 
Could anyone advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for making your code work you can try to copy the jars to the HADOOP_HOME/lib/ folder of all nodes on the cluster and then restart the cluster.